# label weird problem

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a weird label problem . If i introduce something like the code below, even though i create a label with the same attributes but different location , it only displays the first. If i comment the "a" section and leave the details for the b label, the b label is displayed correctly . What is wrong? Regards, Alexandru Badescu

```
                a = new Label();
                a.Name = listaS.ElementAt(i).nrSucursala;
                a.Location = new Point(20,  3);
                a.Text = listaS.ElementAt(i).nrSucursala + "";
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(a);


                b = new Label();
                b.Name = listaS.ElementAt(i).nrSucursala;
                b.Location = new Point(20, 11);
                b.Text = listaS.ElementAt(i).nrSucursala + "";
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: It must be caused by the positioning of your label / panel controls.

Comment: i've looked over the form's properties and they look just fine ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you provided as code snippet it is difficult to say what is wrong. Try narrowing down the problem. Start by the evident that should work and progressively enhance it with other code:

```
var a = new Label();
a.Name = "a name";
a.Location = new Point(20,  3);
a.Text = "a text";
this.panel1.Controls.Add(a);

var b = new Label();
b.Name = "b name";
b.Location = new Point(20, 11);
b.Text = "b text";
this.panel1.Controls.Add(b);
```

Notice how the `a` and `b` variables are locally declared.

Comment: i've introduced something like  your code and now it displays only b :-?

Comment: my Label a and Label b are also declared locally

Comment: What happened when you put this code in a newly created empty winforms application containing a single panel?

Comment: It was the size.. but i don't understand why it worked for a label and not for 2 when i runned the code..

Answer (score 0):

It was the size.. but i don't understand why it worked for a label and not for 2 when i runned the code..